# PayPal webhook all events remain pending

Tags: paypal, webhooks

When I complete a payment with PayPal using a sandbox account, webhook events are listed as "Pending" with an orange icon in the "Webhook events" section of the PayPal developer dashboard, and the log shows that the webhook has not been called. However, when using a different REST API app, the webhook call works perfectly!

I have tried:

- Ensuring that currency is correctly configured
- Changing the "Payment Review" setting to "Off" for each sandbox account
- Making the app call the webhook for all events
- Comparing settings with the other app I made, for which the webhook does get called
- Checking that the webhook causes log output, so there is no error causing the lack of output

What other things could be causing this difference, making webhook calls work for one app but get stuck in "Pending" for another that I created more recently?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I have the same issue

Comment: I mananged to make the problem go away by changing the URL leading to the webhook, but don't know why that helped or if that was the factor that stopped the problem.

Comment: I will try that and let you know, thanks

Comment: I ended up sending a question to the support team and it just started working again for some reason. not sure If they did something on their end or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing in wrong way, i had a test ambient develop and when I was sending events to paypal, the return route was indicating to production ambient. Thats my error and my soluction was buying some stuffs in production ambient.  Summarize, the paypal cant get a response for your event, in other words, paypal cant finish the event. Verify your RETURN URL and CANCEL URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Other thing thats can be a problem is the code of your listening is getting some errors, try to stop the flux of information with a Log::info() (in my case i used that).

Answer (score -1):

Sandbox accounts and REST Apps are free and unlimited, so if one isn't working the way you need it to, the simple solution is to not use it anymore and use any number of new ones you create instead.

But if this remains an issue for you, it seems like you should direct the question to PayPal's support, since you've included no request/response log information to actually review for what might be different about the two apps or accounts' situations that causes one to be pending.

Comment: I have tried this, and I keep having issues. I created about 10 different sandbox accounts and I still get hooks "pending". Then there are times when they work, then they stop working, then they work again.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your URL listener, but you'd have to review your webserver logs or contact PayPal for more details

Comment: I will check again although the mock webhooks work fine. I am able to receive all mock events, and sometimes the sandbox events. I have contacted them to see what they say.